# Django CORS configuration not working despite middleware setup

Tags: python, django, cors

I'm encountering an issue with CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) configuration in my Django project. Despite configuring CORS settings in my `settings.py` and adding the `CorsMiddleware` to the `MIDDLEWARE` list, I still encounter CORS-related errors when making requests from my frontend application.

Here's a summary of my configuration:

`settings.py` (CORS and CSRF settings):

```py
# CORS
CORS_URLS_REGEX = r"^/api/.*$"
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = config("CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST", cast=Csv(), default=["http://localhost:3000"])
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = config("CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS", cast=Csv(), default=["localhost:3000"])
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = config("CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS", default=True, cast=bool)
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
)
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + ["Set-Cookie"]

# CSRF
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = config("CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS", cast=Csv())

CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
```

`settings.py` (MIDDLEWARE):

```py
MIDDLEWARE = (
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
)
```

Despite having these settings in place, when I attempt to make a request from my frontend application (https://example.com) to my Django backend (https://api.example.com/api/v1/), I receive the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/api/v1/' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Also I get this result from Postman:
[image]

Django version: `4.2.1`
django-cors-headers version: `4.3.1`

Comment: List `"corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware"` first in `MIDDLEWARE`.

Comment: @jub0bs I did, but not fixed

Comment: In your browser's Network tab, inspect the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header of the preflight request. For things to work, all the header names listed there must also be listed in `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS`.

Comment: Also, you can safely remove `Set-Cookie` from `CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS`; listing that header name there is pointless.